# Ошибка "expected primary-expression before';' token"

Tags: c++, c, препроцессор

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#define pow(t,r)

using namespace std;

int f1(float y, float x,float t, float r, float pi)
{

    pi = 3.1415;
    t=(-x);
    r=(2);
    cout << "Enter 'x':" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    if(x <= 0){
        y = pow(t,r);
    }
    else if((x<=pi) <= 0){
        y = sin(x);
    }
    else if(x > pi / 2){
        y = 1 + x - pi / 2;
    }
    cout << "y = " << y << endl;
    return (1) ;
}

int f2(float y, float x)
{
    cout << "Enter 'x':" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    if(x < -1){
        y = -5;
    }
    else if(x < 0){
        y = 0;
    }
    else if(x < 1){
        y = x * 5;
    }
    else y = 5;
    cout << "y = " << y << endl;
    return (2) ;
}

int f3(double &x1,double &x2){
    int d=-1;
    if(x1<x2) {
        double d;
        d=x1; x1=x2; x2=d;
        d=1;
    }
    return d>0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Забавно. Работаете с потоками типа `cout`, а

```
#include <iostream>
```

не написали.

Ладно, к делу. Вы объявили

```
#define pow(t,r)
```

т.е. сказали препроцессору — если где встретишь в тексте `pow(..,..)` — выбрось его, замени на пустое место. И препроцессор честно превратил

```
y = pow(t,r);
```

в

```
y = ;
```

Ну и как компилятору это скомпилировать? Вот он и пожаловался, как смог...

P.S. Еще очень интересно, что вы хотели сказать этим выражением:

```
if ((x<=pi) <= 0)
```

А в `f3` все, что вы делаете с `d` внутри `if`, вы делаете с локальной переменной, так что оптимизированный код вашей функции имеет вид

```
int f3(double &x1,double &x2){
    return false;
}
```

Ну, о точности

```
pi = 3.1415;
```

просто молчу.